# Chrome collapsing the width of inline element with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you open the following URL in google chrome you will see the problem, on first load it's ok but if you keep refreshing the width of the 3 items at the top (Bedingungen, Preise and So geht's) collapse. In firefox it's ok but I have no idea why it does it in chrome, anyone see why it might happen or is there a solution? Thanks!

The text is loaded in with Ajax/json and they are inline because I want them to be the width of the text. I don't want to set a fixed width.

http://alexanderlloyd.info/test/

CODE

```
CSS:

#game-nav li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(217, 195, 169);
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    JavaScript:

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var data;
        function loadContent(){ 
            $.ajax({
                url: "json/content.json",
                data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(source){
                    data = source;
                    showInfo();
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("Failed to load content");
                }
            }); 

        }

        loadContent();
            function showInfo(){
                $(".text").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);
        }
       showInfo();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is with your float:left property of li.game-nav
since its updated dynamically it canot adjust properly
try removing float:left from the list and add it to its div container

Comment: it appears to be fixed now? but using position:absolute isn't a good fix, browsers like IE tends screw it